# How to name nested form input with association

Tags: jquery, forms, nested, clone

when I post the form, I need some association between the "vsc" and the "vscitems" - (the amounts)
![enter image description here][1]
Both of these sections can be cloned and the ui is working as expected, but I need to get these items in a database and can't figure out how to change the input name so that I can capture that on the post.

Basically, I can't figure out how to put the make the subrows have the same name. I need to loop over two sections of the form.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="vscrow nest-clone">
<div class="toclone well vsc">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="vsc" name="vsc" class="form-control vscdesc" required #readonly#>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row vscitems">
        <div class="nest-clone inner-wrap">
            <div class="row toclone">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" id="vscpenetration" name="vscpenetration" value="" class="form-control text-right">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                            <input type="number" id="vscpayrate" name="vscpayrate" value="" class="form-control text-right">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <a href="#" class="clone btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="delete btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <a href="#" class="clone btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="delete btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are trying to do this http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/rg72r

Comment: if you are cloning `nest-clone` better to rename those `id`'s inside it

Answer (score 0):

when you are cloning you could group the inputs into arrays, so the names of the the inputs would look like

```
<input name="vcs[0][vscpayrate]" ...
<input name="vcs[0][vscpenetration]" ...
```

Where after [0] will increase every time you clone the fieldset, this will make your post request send an array (vcs) that you can iterate over to get all of the fieldsets

Perhaps something like this

```
   <div id="nest-clone"class="vscrow">
<div id="toclone" data-clone_count="0" class=" well vsc">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="vsc" name="vsc[0][desc]" class="form-control clonable vscdesc" required ></input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row vscitems">
        <div class="nest-clone inner-wrap">
            <div class="row toclone">
                <div class="col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="number" id="vscpenetration" name="vsc[0][penetration]" value="" class="form-control clonable text-right"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
                            <input type="number" id="vscpayrate" name="vsc[0][payrate]" value="" class="form-control clonable text-right"/>
                            <div class="input-group-addon">.00</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
 <a href="#" id="add" class=" btn btn-default">add</a>
```

and jQuery

```
$('#add').click(function() {

    //keeping count of clones 
    $('#toclone').data('clone_count', $('#toclone').data('clone_count') + 1);
    var count = $('#toclone').data('clone_count'),
        newclone = $('#toclone').clone();
    var removebtn = $('<button/>', {
        class: "btn remove btn-default",
        type: 'button',
        html: 'remove'
    })
        .click(function() {
            newclone.remove()
        });
    newclone.find('.clonable').each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        name = name.replace(/(vsc\[)(\d+)(\])/, '$1' + count + '$3')
        $(this).attr('name', name)
    });
    newclone.attr('id', 'clone-' + count).append(removebtn)
        .appendTo('#nest-clone');
});
```

You can test and play with it to adjust it [https://jsfiddle.net/xxeLm8j4/](https://jsfiddle.net/xxeLm8j4/6/)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do Jhony, but I can't figure out how to write the nested loops that would create the array notation! Thanks...

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not explaining this well... I can't post a picture... each vsc element can be cloned AND each vscitem within the vsc can be cloned. What I'm expecting to do is rename all the fields every time something is added or removed.

Comment: That's what the script does, if you look at the names of the inputs on a added clone you'd see that every time you add one the array notation on the name of each input gets incremented by one, making vsc an array of clones   eg : `<input name="vcs[0][vscpayrate]" ...
<input name="vcs[0][vscpenetration]" ... ` the next one will be `<input name="vcs[1][vscpayrate]" ...
<input name="vcs[1][vscpenetration]" ... `and  so on, so when you the oull the input from your request on server you'll have an array of vscitems

Comment: ...but I'm talking about multiple levels of nesting. Is there a resource to hire developers for something at this level.  I've searched and searched, but I'm not familiar with any. Thanks.

Comment: $(".vsc").each(function(i, vsc){
          $(vsc).find('input').each(function(n, vscitem){   
     var vscitemname = $(vscitem).attr( "name" );
     var cleanvscitemname = vscitemname.replace(/\d+/g,'');
     var newvscitemname = cleanvscitemname + i;
     $(vscitem).attr('name', newvscitemname );
    });
   });